# How do I print "Error" is search does not exist inside the CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

Everything works except "Does not exist" part. I want python to spit out "Does not Exist" if there are no matching parameters.

Python code:

```
entercpu = int (input("Enter number of CPU: "))
entermemory = int (input("Enter the amount of memory: "))

import csv

with open('/Users/dhilan/Desktop/test.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    dict_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for d in dict_reader:
        if d['NumCpu'] == str(entercpu) and d['Guest OS'] == 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)' and d['MemoryGB'] == str(entermemory):
            if d =="":
                    print("Does not exists")
            else:
                print('Name: {Name}, CPU: {NumCpu}, Memory: {MemoryGB}, OS: {Guest OS}'.format(**d))
```

It should say "Does not exist" if there is no matching strings inputted by the user in the CSV file. If there is a matching string, it will print the entire line in the CSV matching the entered parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want to print that message if *all* dicts fail to match; you have to wait until you've checked them all.

```
missing = True
for d in dict_reader:
    if d['NumCpu'] == str(entercpu) and d['Guest OS'] == 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)' and d['MemoryGB'] == str(entermemory):
        print('Name: {Name}, CPU: {NumCpu}, Memory: {MemoryGB}, OS: {Guest OS}'.format(**d))
        missing = False

if missing:
    print("Does not Exist")
```

Comment: It doesn't work correctly, it only spits out 1 line then breaks even though it should spit out 5-6 lines depending on the parameters.

Comment: I see -- there can be multiple matches.  Okay ... I'll update this.  There's no way I can test it properly, since you failed to provide your MCVE.